# Material Design Guidelines for choosing the right Composable

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, material-design, material-components-android

[Material3](https://m3.material.io/) from Google is great for applying some consistency in terms of what colors, shapes and typography is used throughout the app.

However, sometimes i struggle with knowing which composables to use in a given situation e.g. should i use list with Dividers or Cards, use an outline text field or normal text, radio buttons or tabs. Is there any documentation that focuses on which type of composables to select for a given situation?

Comment: This would be a design decision and depends on case by case. You have to choose a component (composable) that matches your design if the designs are created using the material design system or create custom components as required.